# Restoring postgres schema results in many syntax errors

Tags: postgresql

Repo dump has this output

```
--
-- Name: add_em(integer, integer); Type: FUNCTION; Schema: public; Owner: developer
--
CREATE FUNCTION public.add_em(x integer, y integer) RETURNS integer LANGUAGE sql AS $ $
SELECT
    x + y;

$ $;

ALTER FUNCTION public.add_em(x integer, y integer) OWNER TO developer;
```

But when I run `psql -f`  to try to restore the database I get this error

```
psql:lib/scripts/repo/structure:87: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$"
LINE 1: ...em(x integer, y integer) RETURNS integer LANGUAGE sql AS $ $
```

Comment: What version of Postgres was this function created in? Per @JGH answer I don't see how this would have not failed on creation.

Comment: Where did the dump from? I don't think pg_dump would have created such a file.

Answer (score 0):

The tag used for [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) must respect the rules of an unquoted identifier (beside being case sensitive and not allowing `$`), so a space is invalid.

```sql
select $a$ test $a$;
 ?column?
----------
  test
(1 row)


select $ $ test $ $;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$"
LINE 1: select $ $ test $ $;
```